# Como remover caracteres de uma string?

Tags: python, string, algoritmo

O programa deve ler duas strings e retirar da primeira string todas as letras que ocorrem na segunda string. Exemplo: Sejam as strings "chocolate" e "oca", então o programa deve imprimir "hlte". Como resolver o problema utilizando conhecimento de strings?
Pseudocódigo:

```
 string1 = raw_input()
 string2 = raw_input()
 stringresultante = caracteres da string1 - caracteres da string2
 print stringresultante
```

Comment: Alguma coisa me diz que já foi respondido antes

Comment: Alguém já fez uma pergunta semelhante?

Comment: @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza Já [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/how-do-i-remove-a-substring-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python) [Aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Perdão, mas não entendi. Irei editar a pergunta.

Comment: sua resposta esta [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Obrigado @MarconcilioSouza

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Como você vai remover um caractere especifico de uma `String` usando outra `String`, você vai precisar fazer um `loop` para percorre a `String` que tem os caracteres "oca" para assim verificar na sua segunda `String` "chocolate".

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
>>>
>>> a = "a!b@c#d$"
>>> b = "!@#$"
>>> for i in range(0,len(b)):
...  a =a.replace(b[i],"")
...
>>> print a
abcd
>>>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Sua resposta foi simples e conciliou os assuntos que já estudei.

Answer (score 2):

```
word1 = 'chocolate'
word2 = 'oca'

for i in word2:
    word1 = word1.replace(i, '')
    
print(word1)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você [edit] e incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/100416).

Answer (score 2):

Em usei algo parecido com o Gustavo Sampaio e com o Marco Souza

```
ex1 = "chocolate"
ex2 = "oca"

for letra in ex2:
   if letra in ex1:    
      ex1 = ex1.replace(letra,'')


print(ex1)
```

O output será:

```
hlte
```

O que este código faz é um loop por cada letra da segunda string, depois verifica se essa letra está no primeiro exemplo e se for verdadeira vai remover essa letra da primeira string e considerar que ex1 passa a ser a palavra "chocolate", mas sem as letras da ex2

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acho que a solução mais pythonica seria usar o método `str.translate`:

```py
string1 = 'chocolate'
string2 = 'oca'

char_rep={k: '' for k in string2}

string1=string1.translate(str.maketrans(char_rep))

print(string1)
```

Retorna:

```
hlte
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa seria essa:

```py
string1 = "chocolate"
string2 = "oca"

result = ''.join(char for char in string1 if char not in string2)

# 'hlte'
print(result)
```

Ou seja, nós criamos uma [*generator expression* (*expressão geradora*, em tradução livre)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) – aquela que também é usada em *list comprehensions* – que diz que:

> *Para cada caractere em `string1`, retorne aquele que não está em `string2`*.

```py
(char for char in string1 if char not in string2)
```

E usamos o [método `str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para juntar os caracteres escolhidos, isto é, para juntar os caracteres que atenderam aquela condição, em uma única *string*, separando-os por `''`, que serve simplesmente para deixar os caracteres bem próximos uns do outros, como em um texto normal.

```py
''.join(...)
```

Isso seria o mesmo que:

```py
string1 = 'chocolate'
string2 = 'oca'

result = ''

for char in string1:
    if char not in string2:
        result += char
```

E essa solução (dada no início) funciona tanto no Python 2, como no Python 3.

A questão, aqui, é que você não estará, de fato, removendo caracteres da *string* base (isto é, você não estará *modificando* a *string* base), mas estará *criando uma nova*, **a partir** da *string* base.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma interessante para resolver esta questão é utilizando a função **[filter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#filter)** juntamente com **[lambda](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#lambda)**. Para isso podemos montar o código da seguinte forma:

```
string1 = 'chocolate'
string2 = 'oca'

resultado = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i not in string2, string1))

print(resultado)
```

Executando este código receberemos como resultado:

```
hlte
```

No caso de querer especificar o valor da `string1` e da `string2`, podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
string1 = input('Digite uma string: ')
string2 = input('Caracteres a ser removidos: ')

resultado = ''.join(filter(lambda i: i not in string2, string1))

print(resultado)
```