# Como mudar os dados de uma coluna em um dataframe do Pandas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, pandas

Dado df1 gostaria de saber como mudar os dados para que fiquem só com os valores dos anos, ou seja, semelhante a df2:

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = ['1936-04-01', '1936-04-02', '1937-05-03', '1937-07-08']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(date1, columns=['datas'])

date2 = ['1936', '1936', '1937', '1937']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(date2, columns=['datas'])
```

Dessa forma, mas em dataframe com muitos dados do tipo datetime desse tipo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas possíveis soluções dependendo da necessidade.

### Solução 1 - tratando a coluna `datas` como String

Considerando que as datas estão no formato YYYY-MM-DD e que a coluna é do tipo object.

```
df1["ano"] = df1["datas"].str[:4]
```

Resultado

```
print(df1)
        datas   ano
0  1936-04-01  1936
1  1936-04-02  1936
2  1937-05-03  1937
3  1937-07-08  1937
```

Veja o `dtypes`

```
print(df1.dtypes)

datas    object
ano      object
dtype: object
```

### Solução 2 - convertendo a coluna `datas` para o tipo `datetime` e pegando o ano

```
df1["ano"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df1["datas"], format="%Y-%m-%d")).year
```

Resultado

```
print(df1)

        datas   ano
0  1936-04-01  1936
1  1936-04-02  1936
2  1937-05-03  1937
3  1937-07-08  1937
```

Tipos

```
print(df1.dtypes)

datas    object
ano       int64
dtype: object
```

**Nota**: Caso queira manter a coluna `datas` com o tipo `datetime`. É preciso fazer o processo em duas etapas

```
df1["datas"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["datas"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df1["ano"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['datas']).year
```

Resultado

```
print(df1)

       datas   ano
0 1936-04-01  1936
1 1936-04-02  1936
2 1937-05-03  1937
3 1937-07-08  1937

print(df1.dtypes)

datas    datetime64[ns]
ano               int64
dtype: object
```

Em tempo, para construir um novo dataframe a partir do primeiro, faça a cópia e depois converta a coluna

```
df2 = df1.copy()
df2["datas"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df2["datas"], format="%Y-%m-%d")).year
```

Resultado

```
print(df2)

   datas
0   1936
1   1936
2   1937
3   1937

print(df2.dtypes)

datas    int64
dtype: object
```

Perceba que neste último exemplo, a coluna `datas` foi sobreposta.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, favor explicar o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta.

Answer (score -2):

Vai precisar fazer um laço de repetição pois assim ira percorre cada valor. Utilizando o "for" você consegue fazer.

Já existe explicação sobre isso. Acredito que irá tirar suas dúvidas.

[Como remover caracteres de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120389/como-remover-caracteres-de-uma-string)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: EVITE usa `for` em dataframes... Muito custoso para processar.

Comment: Obrigado por mim corrigir. Irei evitar a partir de agora